# Weird behavior of cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising()

Tags: python, opencv, parameters

According to [this documentation of opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d1/d79/group__photo__denoise.html#ga4c6b0031f56ea3f98f768881279ffe93), [this link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/photo/doc/denoising.html?highlight=denoising#fastnlmeansdenoising) and [this link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/photo/doc/denoising.html) too:

C++:

```
void fastNlMeansDenoising(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, float h=3, int templateWindowSize=7, int searchWindowSize=21 )
```

Python:

```
cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(src[, dst[, h[, templateWindowSize[, searchWindowSize]]]]) → dst
```

The parameters are (**briefly**) as the following:

- src – Input image.
- dst – Output image with the same size and type as src.
- templateWindowSize – Size in pixels of the template patch. Should be odd.
- searchWindowSize – Size in pixels of the window. Should be odd.
- h – Parameter regulating filter strength.

As I know, in Python, we can take the dst/output variable out of the method to be: `dst = cv2.method(input, param1, param2, ..., paramx)`. And we don't need to put anything in its place inside the method (i.e we don't need to do this: `dst = cv2.method(input, None, param1, param2, ..., paramx)`.
Although this works with the different OpenCV methods, it does not work with `fastNlMeansDenoising`.
The following code will clarify my issue:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def thresh(filename):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #without adding None instead of dst
    test_1 = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray, 31, 7, 21)
    cv2.imwrite('test_1.jpg', test_1)

    # Adding None instead of dst
    test_2 = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray, None, 31, 7, 21)
    cv2.imwrite('test_2.jpg', test_2)

    # putting dst inside the method
    test_3 = np.empty(gray.shape, np.uint8)
    cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray, test_3, 31, 7, 21)
    cv2.imwrite('test_3.jpg', test_3)

    # Adding the input params
    test_4 = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray, h=31, templateWindowSize=7,
                                      searchWindowSize=21)
    cv2.imwrite('test_4.jpg', test_4)

    blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 31, 7, 21)
    cv2.imwrite('blur.jpg', blur)
    blur_ = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 31, 7, 21, None)
    cv2.imwrite('blur_.jpg', blur_)
    blur__ = np.empty(gray.shape, np.uint8)
    cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 31, 7, 21, blur__)
    cv2.imwrite('blur__.jpg', blur__)


thresh('test.png')
```

Here is the input image:

[image]

As you'll notice if you run the code, test_2.jpg, test_3.jpg and test_4.jpg are similar. And test_1.jpg is the same as `gray` (as if `test_1` didn't receive the output of `fastNlMeansDenoising`).

However this is not the case with `bilateralFilter`: blur.jpg, blur_.jpg and blur__.jpg are all the same although I repeat the same process that I did with `fastNlMeansDenoising`.

Is there any explanation for this? Why should we add `None` to `fastNlMeansDenoising` parameters?

Comment: "And we don't need to put anything in its place inside the method" -- Incorrect. That only works if you use keyword arguments, otherwise the parameters are assigned in order. The additional overload in more recent releases might also complicate things a bit -- prefer to write it as in `test_4` case, then it's unambiguous.

Comment: @DanMašek I agree with you, but why I see different behaviour when I used `bilateralFilter`?

Comment: @DanMašek, if I don't put `None` in the method params, the parameters will be assigned in order, which means in this case, the output will be saved to '31' which will necessarily throw an error because of incompatibility of types (31 is int and the dst should be array). But I don't get any errors, which is still weird!

Comment: In `bilateralFilter`, `dst` is the fifth argument (and first one that is optional). You called it with either 4 arguments (so `dst` being fifth and optional gets default value and all is fine), or with 5 arguments (again ok, since you're not mixing them up). So, it behaves the same way, but since `dst` is much further back in the argument list, there are fewer chances for a mixup.

Comment: As for why the mixup doesn't cause an explicit  error -- the Python bindings work in somewhat mysterious ways (especially for output arguments, and overloaded functions add some more complexity) . I'll need some time to refresh my memory before I can properly explain what happens there in this particular case.

Comment: Okay then I'll wait your answer :-)

Comment: When the C++ parameter is Input/OutputArray, the python function will accept any python object. Then it tries to [convert it](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp#L275) to a `cv::Mat`. (If that fails, it tries to convert to `UMat`. If that fails, and there are overloads, it tries to resolve them in same way. If nothing matches you get error.) Now, since the C++ API allows scalars to be used for some operations that take Input/OutputArray, the conversion function also allows scalars. For example, a single integer will become a 4x1 float64 mat with the value..

Comment: in first row and rest zeros. Same thing for single float. Tuples (of numbers) become single column mats with as many rows as the tuple has elements, again float64. Finally arrays, but let's not get into that. So, everything up to the invocation of the actual C++ function is OK. Next is a feature of the C++ API. When given an output `cv::Mat` that has incorrect shape or datatype, it's automatically reallocated to satisfy the requirements.

Comment: I think (although now i'm having some doubts, let me check that)... that there's a slight side effect of this behaviour regarding Python. Let's say that in `cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray, test_3, 31, 7, 21)` the `test_3` numpy array was of wrong shape or type. In that case, the function would run fine, but since the newly allocated `Mat` no longer references the underlying numpy buffer, `test_3` would remain unmodified. And since you don't capture the return value, you'd lose the actual result. | Update: checked it and yes, that's the case.

Comment: That seems clear now! Please put all the comments to answer and post it.

Comment: Yeah, working on it (it will take a bit to write it up properly).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Function `fastNlMeansDenoising`

Let's first look a the signature of [the Python function](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d1/d79/group__photo__denoise.html#ga4c6b0031f56ea3f98f768881279ffe93):

```
cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(src[, dst[, h[, templateWindowSize[, searchWindowSize]]]]) → dst
```

The way the brackets (`[]`) are nested means that the 2nd-5th argument are optional, but as long as they are passed in as positional arguments, the sequence needs to remain the same (i.e. you can't skip any).

That means that using positional arguments only, there are 5 possibilities:

```
cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(src) → dst
cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(src, dst) → dst
cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(src, dst, h) → dst
cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(src, dst, h, templateWindowSize) → dst
cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(src, dst, h, templateWindowSize, searchWindowSize) → dst
```

Any optional arguments that are not provided will use a default value. The default values used can be deduced from the corresponding C++ function signature.

```
void fastNlMeansDenoising(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, float h=3, int templateWindowSize=7, int searchWindowSize=21)
```

For the last 3 arguments, it's obvious -- `h=3`, `templateWindowSize=7`, and `searchWindowSize=21`. In the Python bindings, `OutputArray` parameters implicitly have `None` (Unlike in C++ API, the Python variants also return the outputs).

---

With that in mind, your first variant

```
test_1 = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray, 31, 7, 21)
```

means

```
test_1 = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(src=gray, dst=31, h=7, templateWindowSize=21, searchWindowSize=21)
```

i.e. `h` is a lot smaller than you intended, and `templateWindowSize` much larger. That's why the result is different.

We will explore why setting `dst` to 31 does not cause any explicit errors to be raised later in the answer.

---

The fourth variant is IMHO the best way to skip `dst`:

```
test_4 = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray, h=31, templateWindowSize=7, searchWindowSize=21)
```

You're unlikely to mix things up when using keyword arguments explicitly.

The second variant (passing `None` as second argument) is OK.

The third variant is useful in loops, by allowing you to reuse a temporary array in subsequent iterations and avoid re-allocations (which can be costly). However, there is a catch -- the array has to have exactly the required shape and data type. If not, it won't be modified (but the function will still return a newly allocated array holding the result, which you need to capture).

The reason for this we become evident as you read on.

---

## Function `bilateralFilter`

You mentioned [`bilateralFilter`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga9d7064d478c95d60003cf839430737ed) for comparison, so let's examine it as well.

```
cv.bilateralFilter(src, d, sigmaColor, sigmaSpace[, dst[, borderType]]) → dst
```

That means there are those 3 possibilities to call this using positional arguments only:

```
cv.bilateralFilter(src, d, sigmaColor, sigmaSpace) → dst
cv.bilateralFilter(src, d, sigmaColor, sigmaSpace, dst) → dst
cv.bilateralFilter(src, d, sigmaColor, sigmaSpace, dst, borderType) → dst
```

Notice that since the `dst` argument occurs much later in the sequence, there's only one possible mistake you could make regarding it -- pass in a border type instead.

In your code example, you only used either 4 or 5 arguments, never even used `borderType`, and in all cases `dst` got a meaningful value.

To sum it up: The functions behave consistently, but the fewer optional arguments that follow `dst`, the fewer opportunities to shoot yourself in the foot.

---

## How the Python Bindings Work

Due to the size of the OpenCV code base that needs to be exposed to Python, the wrappers around the C++ functions are automatically generated. Due to the complexity of the API, some of the behaviour might not be immediately obvious unless you study the implementation in detail. (And since the actual binding code is autogenerated at build time, it's better if you compile OpenCV locally to inspect the generated implementation)

Let's look at a section of the code generated to wrap `fastNlMeansDenoising`:

```
static PyObject* pyopencv_cv_fastNlMeansDenoising(PyObject* , PyObject* args, PyObject* kw)
{
    using namespace cv;

    {
    PyObject* pyobj_src = NULL;
    Mat src;
    PyObject* pyobj_dst = NULL;
    Mat dst;
    float h=3;
    int templateWindowSize=7;
    int searchWindowSize=21;

    const char* keywords[] = { "src", "dst", "h", "templateWindowSize", "searchWindowSize", NULL };
    if( PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kw, "O|Ofii:fastNlMeansDenoising", (char**)keywords, &pyobj_src, &pyobj_dst, &h, &templateWindowSize, &searchWindowSize) &&
        pyopencv_to(pyobj_src, src, ArgInfo("src", 0)) &&
        pyopencv_to(pyobj_dst, dst, ArgInfo("dst", 1)) )
    {
        ERRWRAP2(cv::fastNlMeansDenoising(src, dst, h, templateWindowSize, searchWindowSize));
        return pyopencv_from(dst);
    }
    }

    // Clear Python error, try the same for UMat

    // Clear Python error, try overload with Mat

    // Clear Python error, try overload with UMat

    return NULL;
}
```

First, [`PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/arg.html#c.PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords) is used to parse the function arguments and assign their values (or leave the pre-set defaults if optional and missing) to corresponding C++ variables.

It's important to note that when the type of the corresponding C++ argument is `Input/OutputArray`, it is parsed as a Python object (the `O` in the format string) -- that means it can be anything at this stage.

Once the parameters are parsed, [`pyopencv_to`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp#L275) is used to convert the Python object to a `cv::Mat`. Since many OpenCV functions (e.g. [`cv::add`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga10ac1bfb180e2cfda1701d06c24fdbd6)) allow some of the input arguments (and potentially output arguments as well) to be both arrays as well as scalars, the Python bindings support this as well.

The conversion to `cv::Mat` works as follows:

- If the argument is `None`, leave an empty `Mat`.
- If the argument is an integer (scalar), create a `Mat` with 4 rows and 1 column and datatype of 64bit floating point value. Set first row to the value of the provided integer, and the rest to 0.
- If the argument is a float (scalar) do the same thing as for the integer (above).
- If the argument is a tuple of numbers, create a `Mat` with `n` rows and 1 column and datatype of 64bit floating point value, where `n` is the number of elements in the tuple. Each row holds one element, in sequence.
- Finally, handle arrays (out of scope for this answer).

That means that when you called `cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray, 31, 7, 21)`, the integer `31` became a 4x1 single channel `Mat` with 64bit floating point elements. Therefore the underlying C++ function could be invoked without an issue. Now, why didn't it complain about the `Mat` being the wrong size and data type to store the output?

---

## How `OutputArray`s Work

Since the C++ API uses output array arguments in favour of return values, it needs to be able to support situations where the size of the result cannot be determined before invoking the function. To deal with that issue, in situations when given an empty `Mat`, or a `Mat` of incorrect shape or data type, the `Mat` is re-created (a new buffer is allocated, etc.) to satisfy the requirements. Since `Mat` is basically a smart pointer to the underlying image buffer, this works correctly, and in C++ quite predictably (IMHO) -- even if reallocation happens, the instance of `Mat` you provided as output parameter will correctly refer to the new data.

This explains why the `31` as `dst` was OK -- it produced `Mat` of wrong shape and type, but that just got reallocced, and everything was fine.

However, this nice feature introduces a little snag in the Python API. When a numpy array is provided for an `Input/OutputArray` argument, a `Mat` instance is created which shares the underlying buffer that holds the values. That means the operation is fast (since no data is copied), and that the numpy array automatically reflects changes done on the `Mat`. However, if OpenCV reallocates the `Mat` due to incorrect shape/type, a new buffer is allocated and the original numpy array remains unchanged.

This can be easily demonstrated:

```
>>> a = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
>>> b = a + 1
>>> c = np.zeros(a.shape, np.float32)
>>> c
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
>>> cv2.add(a, b, c)
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3]], dtype=uint8)
>>> c
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
>>> d = np.zeros_like(a)
>>> cv2.add(a, b, d)
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3]], dtype=uint8)
>>> d
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: @singrium There you go. Let me know if anything needs improving.

Comment: This is definitely one of the most (if not the best) well explained answers I've ever seen in Stack Overflow. I can't say more.

Comment: This is an incredible answer